# Creating a list in vb

Tags: vb.net

Until now, I have been using List(of T) Class, which is a typed list of objects where I would have the Name of the object and 3 more properties (such as Age, LastName and MiddleName) .

For now I have populated the class with about 100 names. My end goal is to populate about 1000 up to 2000 names and to retrieve the other properties from that name (Age, LastName and MiddleName).

I would like to ask you for your oppinion on this, if it is the right way to use  this method for this problem or if I should use something else.
I was thinking about using a LINQ solution, but I am not sure if it's to my advantage. Please let me know what you think.

Useful Links:

List of T Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

LINQ 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx

Comment: You use linq to query collections. So you can use both.

Comment: My first thought is: try using a Dictionary(of String, Object). String contains your names and Object your class/structure containing the rest of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no REAL answer anyone can give you on this without knowing a lot more information about how you intend to use the data structure.

Dot net comes with a confusing myriad of different collection types, some might say TOO MANY, but each type has it's own benefits and limitations. You can even wrap them into custom collections...

You need to fully understand what you need to do then chose the type you think will be best suited to your application. This article is a good place to start..

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

On the plus side... you have already passed the first step of understanding you need to use such a structure. Once your code is written that way it is generally not a HUGE hassle changing the collection type later to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your useful input. :)